# How do i change the way visual studio code auto corrects curly braces?

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code, curly-braces

I prefer my curly braces looking like this:

```
function eg()
{

}
```

But when I try to format my code, vscode auto corrects to this:

```
function eg() {

}
```

Is there any plugins that I can download or setting that I can tweak to change this?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
"javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true;

"javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": true;

"typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": true;

"typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true;
```

Comment: and what about PHP?

Comment: @AbuKhan Please make sure to include the language you are using in future questions